# Updating the xml data nodes by passing the SQL variable

Tags: sql-server, xml, nodes

I have the following XML and I need to update the specified one based on the parameter:

```
<DOPremium>
    <BasePremium>337500</BasePremium>
    <TotalPremium>337500</TotalPremium>
    <NettPremium>337500</NettPremium>
    <GrossPremium>337500</GrossPremium>
    <OptionId>0</OptionId>
</DOPremium>
<DOPremium>
     <BasePremium>337500</BasePremium>
     <TotalPremium>337500</TotalPremium>
     <NettPremium>337500</NettPremium>
     <GrossPremium>337500</GrossPremium>
     <OptionId>1</OptionId>
</DOPremium>
<DOPremium>
     <BasePremium>337500</BasePremium>
     <TotalPremium>337500</TotalPremium>
     <NettPremium>337500</NettPremium>
     <GrossPremium>337500</GrossPremium>
     <OptionId>2</OptionId>
</DOPremium>
```

I'm trying to update the respective nodes based on the selection of the `DOPremium` object, but I'm not able to do that. Can someone verify where I'm wrong?

```
SET @NewXmlValue = N' <BasePremium>[sql:variable("@R15_premium")]</BasePremium>'
SET @DataXml.modify('delete /*/Premiums/DOPremium/BasePremium[sql:variable("@OptionID")]')          
SET @DataXml.modify('insert sql:variable("@NewXmlValue") into (/*/Premiums/DOPremium[sql:variable("@OptionID")])[1]')           

-- Add TotalPremium
SET @NewXmlValue = N' <TotalPremium>[sql:variable("@R15_premium")]</TotalPremium>'
SET @DataXml.modify('delete /*/Premiums/DOPremium/TotalPremium[sql:variable("@OptionID")]')         
SET @DataXml.modify('insert sql:variable("@NewXmlValue") into (/*/Premiums/DOPremium[sql:variable("@OptionID")])[1]')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, first of all, this can't work:

```
SET @NewXmlValue = N'<BasePremium>[sql:variable("@R15_premium")]</BasePremium>'
```

`sql:variable()` is only interpreted as a function in an XQuery operation. This isn't an XQuery operation, so it will just textually insert `sql:variable(...)`. If you want an actual XML node with the text value of the variable, you have to be a little more roundabout:

```
SET @NewXmlValue = '';
SET @NewXmlValue = (SELECT @NewXmlValue.query('<BasePremium>{sql:variable("@R15_premium")}</BasePremium>'));
```

This approach (and others) can be found in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/xquery/xml-construction-xquery). (In this very simple case concatenating the strings in T-SQL also works, of course, but in general that's not a good idea because it doesn't take care of escaping the XML when necessary.)

The syntax for selecting the desired `DOPremium` node also needs work -- `/BasePremium[sql:variable("@OptionID")]` is legal, but it means "the `BasePremium` node that, sequentially numbering from 1, has number `@OptionID`". If `@OptionID` is supposed to match what's in `OptionID`, that's not the way to write it.

If your intent was to write "change the contents of the `BasePremium` value of the node with `OptionID` text equal to `@OptionID` to the value `@R15_premium`", here's how you do that (well, one way to do that):

```
SET @DataXml.modify('
    replace value of (
        /*
        /Premiums
        /DOPremium[child::OptionId/.=sql:variable("@OptionID")]
        /BasePremium
        /text()
    )[1] 
    with sql:variable("@R15_premium")')
```

And something similar for `TotalPremium`. You can, of course, also replace entire nodes, but that seems unnecessary here.